# VB Script to Interact With Internet Explorer "Choose File to Upload" Dialog Window

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, dialog

I need to upload a file using the "Choose File to Upload" window using VB Script.  I've been able to navigate to the page and "click" the button to open the window, but can't interact with it.

```
On Error Resume Next
Const PAGE_LOADED = 4
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SHL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Call IE.Navigate("www.myURL.com")
IE.Visible = True
Do Until IE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep(100) : Loop

IE.Document.all.username.Value = "somebody@domain.com"
IE.Document.all.password.Value = "password"
IE.Document.all.tenantName.Value = "tenantName"
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    msgbox "Error: " & err.Description
End If
IE.document.Forms(0).Submit
Wait IE, 500

IE.Navigate "www.PageWhereButtonExists.com"
Wait IE, 500

REM This opens a "Choose File to Upload" Dialog window, but I'm unable to interact with it.
IE.Document.getElementByID("P1_FILE").Click

Set IE = Nothing

Sub Wait(IE, SleepInterval)
    Do
        WScript.Sleep SleepInterval
    Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
```

Comment: Post what did you do so far !

Comment: I updated the original posting.